# javadoc @docRoot

Tags: java, javadoc

Can anyone show me an example of that javadoc tag?

I don't understand very well how to use it in the code

Answer (score 6):

The [javadoc documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/windows/javadoc.html#CHDBACBF) has a couple good examples. It always points to the root of the documentation, so if there's something you want to include on every page, you use it to find the javadoc root, since a relative path would be different from page to page

For example, to include your company's logo at the top of every generated documentation page, you might put `logo.png` in the root of the documentation and then add:

```
<img src="{@docRoot}/logo.png">
```

to the javadoc header

Comment: so is it not used into the source code? what do you mean for javadoc header?

Comment: @xdevel, to build off of Michael's example, you can think of `@docRoot` as being conceptually similar to HTML's `<base>` tag.

Comment: @xdevel2000 The Javadoc tool supports adding something to the header of every page by passing it the `-header` flag, so you could do `javadoc -header '<img src="{@docRoot}/logo.png">'`

Comment: @Michael > Under Windows XP/7/2008/2003, I'm not able to run your command line with -header because the < tag is interpreted as redirection. Any idea ?

Comment: @Zorg: make sure the quoting is right. If it still does not work, open a new question, showing your complete command line.

Answer (score -3):

These are few tag below

```
@author  //this will give name of author

@see     //it is used to point to refrence

@since   //this will give from which version it is included

@link    // this is used to provide link to another file
```

example :http://www.docjar.net/html/api/java/util/Collections.java.html

doc standard :http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/index-137868.html#tag

Comment: This does not answer the question at all, question is about `docRoot`.